# jQuery change event on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I just added the query lib to my web app and tested with simple alert:

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                alert('jquery is working');
            }); 
</script>
```

And works fine. However when i want to implement an "change" event on my dropdown

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" />"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $("#projectKey").change(function() {
            alert($('option:selected', $(this)).text());
        });
</script>
```

it displays me no alert, basically nothing is happening. My drop down is the following:

```
<select id="projectKey" name="projectKey">
    <option value="AM">AM</option>
    <option value="AIL">AIL</option>
    <option value="NEB">NEB</option>
    <option value="SSP">SSP</option>
</select>
```

Of course i tried to simplify the javascript, just o have

```
$("#projectKey").change(function() {
            alert("test");
});
```

but still no joy. It will be something with the selector or the drop down. Tried also "select#projectKey" but the result was of course the same. Any idea what i am doing wrong?

Comment: You're binding events before the elements exist. Use a DOM ready handler, move the bind to the bottom of the page, or use event delegation.

Comment: Thanks! It make sense! I see now what was the issue, but i would like to understand it more deeply. Could you please explain me this on few lines or point me somewhere to read it myself. But as i said thank you, helped me lot! (my first jquery function is live :) )

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should've kept that DOM ready function

```
$(function() {
    $("#projectKey").change(function() {
        alert( $('option:selected', this).text() );
    });
});
```

The document isn't ready if you added the javascript before the elements in the DOM, you have to either use a DOM ready function or add the javascript after the elements, the usual place is right before the `</body>` tag

Comment: Its working now! Thanks for it! Could you please explain me briefly what is the difference? Or point me somewhere where i could find it myself why my solution was not working

Comment: Thanks exactly this is what i wanted!

Answer (score 3):

Please change your javascript function as like below....

```
$(function () {
        $("#projectKey").change(function () {
            alert($('option:selected').text());
        });
    });
```

You do not need to use `$(this)` in alert.

Comment: use `$(this)` in case you have multiple dropdowns, and needs value for this element particularly.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use this javascript

```
$(function () {
    $("#projectKey").change(function () {
        alert($('#projectKey option:selected').text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The html

```
<select id="drop"  name="company" class="company btn btn-outline   dropdown-toggle" >
   <option value="demo1">Group Medical</option>
   <option value="demo">Motor Insurance</option>
</select>
```

Script.js

```
$("#drop").change(function () {                            
   var category= $('select[name=company]').val() // Here we can get the value of selected item
   alert(category); 
});
```