# How to populate textbox based on dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have to populate my textbox based on the dropdown value from a single table....
Here is my table:
[TableStructure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ix4dv.jpg)
[table content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vC3Ks.jpg)

Here when i select category 1 from dropdown i want the textbox value to be 400(price), and for category 2 it should populate 500 and so on.... I have already populated dropdown value from db, please help me with the textbox value.

Controller:

```
         public function viewcatprice()
            {
               $this->load->model('JcMeetingExpense_model');
               $data['query1'] = $this->JcMeetingExpense_model->viewcatprice();   
               $this->load- 
                        >view('JcMeetingExpense/jc_meeting_expense',$data);
            }
```

Model:

```
          function viewcatprice()
           {
             $query = $this->db->select('*')->from('jc_price_master')->get();
             return $query->result();
           }
```

View:

```
     <label for="catprice"></label>
     <select class="form-control" name="category">
        <?php   
        foreach($query1 as $row)
        { 
          echo '<option value="'.$row->category.'">'.$row- 
          >category.'</option>';
        }
        ?>
        </select>
         <tr>
         <td class="colone">Amount Per Head:</td>
         <td class="coltwo"></td>
         <td class="colthree"><input type="number" name="num5"  id="num5" 
         class="input-field" name="field1" style="width:35%;" />
         </td>
         </tr>
```

Comment: What is the structure of your `$row` object? Try `$row['category']` to access it. As well, make sure that you are passing the MySql result, not the query itself (as your initial variable is `$query1`). Otherwise, can you post some of the surrounding pieces of data?

Comment: pls see my edited quetsion now

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [jQuery change event on dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976497/jquery-change-event-on-dropdown)

or if you prefer not to use jQuery, please use the "onchange" attribute of HTML tag and handle it in JS

Answer (score 0):

View Code

```
 <select class="form-control" name="category" id='cat_id'>
    <?php   
    foreach($query1 as $row)
    { 
      echo '<option value="'.$row->category.'">'.$row- 
      >category.'</option>';
    }
    ?>
    </select>

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $("#cat_id").on('change', function() {
    var cat_id = $(this).val();

    if(cat_id){
           $.ajax ({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php_file_that_select_price_from_category_id.php',
            data: { cat_id: cat_id },
            success : function(response) {
                var response = $.parseJSON(response);
                $('#num5').val(response.jc_price_master); 

            },error:function(e){
            alert("error");}
        });
     }
  });
});
```

Controller Code for ajax

```
 public function ajax_price_list() 
 { 
   $this->load->helper('url'); 
   $this->load->model('JcMeetingExpense_model'); 
   $data['jc_price_master'] = $this->JcMeetingExpense_model->getprice(); 
   //$this->load->view('JcMeetingExpense/jc_meeting_expense',$data); you do not have to load view here
   echo jason_encode($data);
 }
```

Comment: Hey i tried but still it's not working. i made these changes, pls have a look.. Controller :-     public function ajax_price_list()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('JcMeetingExpense_model');
        $data['jc_price_master'] = $this->JcMeetingExpense_model->getprice();
        $this->load->view('JcMeetingExpense/jc_meeting_expense',$data);
    }

Comment: Model :-    function getprice()
     {
        $this -> db -> select('price');
        $this -> db -> where('category',$category);
        $query = $this -> db -> get('jc_price_master');
        return $query->result();
     }

Comment: And in ajax url i have used this :- url: '<?php echo site_url('JcMeetingExpense/ajax_price_list'); ?>'

Comment: Can you please confirm is ajax called or not ??

Comment: have you made controller changes?

Comment: yes i have posted my controller code above pls see to it

Comment: In your Controller, You are loading view which is incorrect. Cause when you call AJAX you do not need to load view, just echo or return jason decoded response.

Comment: echo jason_encode($data); i changed this to echo json_encode($data);

Comment: this is my model code:  function getprice()
     {
        $this -> db -> select('price');
        $this -> db -> where('category');
        $query = $this -> db -> get('jc_price_master');
        return $query->result(); 
     }